# flex box item width shrink to text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This code tries to shrink the radio button label which is a `span` tag coloured in "yellow" to just match the string to the right of the radio icon.

The current problem is that the `span' goes too close to the next radio icon that if the mobile user wanting to click the second icon could hit the first radio button by mistake since the`span` is also clickable.

[image]

```css
.radio-group {
    background-color: red;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    -ms-flex-flow: row;
    flex-flow: row;
}

.radio-item {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    -ms-flex-flow: row;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: baseline;
}

.radio-icon {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}

.radio-label {
    background-color: yellow;
    -webkit-flex: 15;
    -ms-flex: 15;
    flex: 15;
}
```

```html
<template name="radio">
  <div class="radio-group">
    {{#each value}}
      <label class="radio-item">
        <input class="radio-icon" type="radio" name={{group}} checked={{value}} value={{name}}>
        <span class="radio-label">{{caption}}</span>
      </label>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: it is not the span, it is the label which is clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use some margin on the `radio-item`like below.

```
.radio-item {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    -ms-flex-flow: row;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: baseline;
    margin-right:30px; /* add margin here */
}
```

```css
.radio-group {
    background-color: red;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    -ms-flex-flow: row;
    flex-flow: row;
}

.radio-item {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    -ms-flex-flow: row;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: baseline;
    margin-right:30px;
}

.radio-icon {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}

.radio-label {
    background-color: yellow;
    -webkit-flex: 15;
    -ms-flex: 15;
    flex: 15;
}
```

```html
<div name="radio">
  <div class="radio-group">
      <label class="radio-item">
        <input class="radio-icon" type="radio" name={{group}} checked={{value}} value={{name}}>
        <span class="radio-label">{{caption}}</span>
      </label>
      <label class="radio-item">
        <input class="radio-icon" type="radio" name={{group}} checked={{value}} value={{name}}>
        <span class="radio-label">{{caption}}</span>
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```